# C++ trouble with reading from file to buffer and writing back to file

Tags: file, input, char, buffer, output

I wrote a very complex program, which is now bugging out one one last thing:
This is what I do:

I open an input file. I read the input file - char for char, into a buffer.
I then write to an output file from the buffer.

After the file is opened and read - the char arrays off the buffer look exactly like the file.
The input file includes any possible symbol. In fact - if the input file is a .jpg image, I should be able to (after changeing the extension to .dat) read it into my buffers, write it out into an output .dat file, then change the extension back to .jpg and see the original image.

I ran a test on a simple 2KB large .txt file (made a .txt file, changed extension to .dat and ran my program).
If the input file is consisted only of simple characters (like, say, a stream of numbers 1234215...) only - the output file is the same (and its size is also 2KB).

If the input file is consisted of simple characters AND there are new lines (if I've hit ENTER, i think that is char with ACSII code 13, but I suspect some other symbols cause this too) - the file is read to my buffers correctly (all 2048 characters of it, since its size is 2KB, are the same as in the file, even the ENTERS), but after I write it back into an output file, the output file *looks* the same, it seems to have the same amount of characters (nothing is missing, there is nothing extra) but it is larger in size (for example - if the input is 2KB, the output is 2.33KB).

This should happen - I suspect there is a corruption somewhere but I can't detect it and I don't know where to look.

this is how I write to the file:

```
f=fopen("izlaz.dat","w");
file1 = FS::open(filename1, 'r');
long cnt = 0;
while(1) {
    if(file1->eof()==0) {
        char rb[1];
        file1->read(1,rb);
        fwrite(rb,1,1,f);
        cnt++;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "cnt = " << cnt << std::endl;
        fclose(f);
        break;
    }
}
```

file1->read(1,rb) reads 1 char to rb

when writing or reading to my buffers, which are basically char arrays, I use 
char input; buffer[pos] = input;    // write to buffer
char output = buffer[pos];    //read from buffer

Ive also tried to memcpy from char input to buffer[pos] and from buffer[pos] to char output but that had no effect on the corruption (it was still corrupted)

Sorry for the wall of text - I hope someone can help out. I've been trying on my own for 3 days :S

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open file in binary mode (`"wb"`):

```
f=fopen("izlaz.dat","wb");
```

[Documentation:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen)

> File access mode flag "b" can optionally be specified to open a file [in binary mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes). This flag has no effect on POSIX systems, but on Windows, for example, it disables special handling of '\n' and '\x1A'.